# Upgraded from Wheezy to Jessie, but aptitude still hits wheezy URLs

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, aptitude, debian-jessie

I upgraded Wheezy to Jessie by following the [release notes - chapter 4](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html), but now when I do an `aptitude update` I get URLs containing wheezy in them:

```
root@debian:/home/paullik# aptitude update
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease 
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/contrib i386 Packages 
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en   
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources  
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Sources
Get: 1 http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [229 B]
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
Get: 2 http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [229 B]
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en
Get: 3 http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [2,023 B]
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/contrib Translation-en
Get: 4 http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [781 B]
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.ro.debian.org jessie-backports/main i386 Packages    
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy InRelease
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Sources
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main i386 Packages
Get: 5 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get: 6 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get: 7 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get: 8 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get: 9 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get: 10 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get: 11 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Get: 12 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en [162 B]
Get: 13 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Get: 14 https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en [162 B]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en
Fetched 3,262 B in 8s (366 B/s)
```

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

#backports
deb http://ftp.ro.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Is this OK?
How can I remove the Wheezy URLs?

PS: `apt-get update` has the same output.
The upgrade process went fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` I had another repo that pointed to `wheezy`.
I changed that to `jessie` and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

For others reading this:

`Hit https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy` is not a distribution managed repository. You have to maintain/update foreign repositories yourself. As you already mentioned, you fixed it already.